# How is embedding matrix being trained in this code snippet?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, word-embedding

I'm following the code of a coursera assignment which implements a NER tagger using  a bidirectional LSTM.

But I'm not able to understand how the embedding matrix is being updated. In the following code, `build_layers` has a variable `embedding_matrix_variable` which acts an input the the LSTM. However it's not getting updated anywhere.

Can you help me understand how embeddings are being trained?

```
def build_layers(self, vocabulary_size, embedding_dim, n_hidden_rnn, n_tags):
    initial_embedding_matrix = np.random.randn(vocabulary_size, embedding_dim) / np.sqrt(embedding_dim)
    embedding_matrix_variable = tf.Variable(initial_embedding_matrix, name='embedding_matrix', dtype=tf.float32)

    forward_cell =  tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(
        tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=n_hidden_rnn, forget_bias=3.0),
        input_keep_prob=self.dropout_ph,
        output_keep_prob=self.dropout_ph,
        state_keep_prob=self.dropout_ph
    )

    backward_cell =  tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(
        tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=n_hidden_rnn, forget_bias=3.0),
        input_keep_prob=self.dropout_ph,
        output_keep_prob=self.dropout_ph,
        state_keep_prob=self.dropout_ph
    )

    embeddings = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding_matrix_variable, self.input_batch)

    (rnn_output_fw, rnn_output_bw), _ =  tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(
        cell_fw=forward_cell, cell_bw=backward_cell,
        dtype=tf.float32,
        inputs=embeddings,
        sequence_length=self.lengths
    )

    rnn_output = tf.concat([rnn_output_fw, rnn_output_bw], axis=2)
    self.logits = tf.layers.dense(rnn_output, n_tags, activation=None)


def compute_loss(self, n_tags, PAD_index):
    """Computes masked cross-entopy loss with logits."""
    ground_truth_tags_one_hot = tf.one_hot(self.ground_truth_tags, n_tags)
    loss_tensor = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=ground_truth_tags_one_hot, logits=self.logits)

    mask = tf.cast(tf.not_equal(self.input_batch, PAD_index), tf.float32)
    self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(loss_tensor, mask), axis=-1) / tf.reduce_sum(mask, axis=-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

In TensorFlow, variables are not usually updated directly (i.e. by manually setting them to a certain value), but rather they are trained using an optimization algorithm and automatic differentiation.

When you define a [tf.Variable](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable), you are adding a node (that maintains a state) to the computational graph. At training time, if the loss node depends on the state of the variable that you defined, TensorFlow will compute the gradient of the loss function with respect to that variable by automatically following the chain rule through the computational graph. Then, the optimization algorithm will make use of the computed gradients to update the values of the trainable variables that took part in the computation of the loss.

Concretely, the code that you provide builds a TensorFlow graph in which the loss `self.loss` depends on the weights in `embedding_matrix_variable` (i.e. there is a path between these nodes in the graph), so TensorFlow will compute the gradient with respect to this variable, and the optimizer will update its values when minimizing the loss. It might be useful to inspect the TensorFlow graph using [TensorBoard](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/graph_viz).